# What is the most efficient way to scan in thousands of pictures?

Tags: scanning, pictures

My parents have a number of really large albums and the pictures are starting to face in a lot of cases so we thought it would be a good idea to scan in all the pictures and move them to online albums.  The issue is that the task is daunting given that there are thousands of pictures.

Are there any services or ideas on how to scan in albums of pictures that won't take up hundreds of man hours for me?

Comment: Are they glued into the albums or removable?

Comment: @slhck - they are removable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many years ago I used [ScanCafe](http://www.scancafe.com/) to scan several rolls of APS film for me.

This time around, I might use [DigMyPics](http://www.digmypics.com/getTheRealTruth.aspx)

ScanCafe offers this helpful [table comparing several competitors](http://www.scancafe.com/pricing/pricecomparison) that offer a similar photo scanning service.

Answer (score 2):

Photo Scanning can be divided into 4 classifications.

1. The big production locations like those named above and a number of others where you will most likely have to box your photos up and send them to their central scanning location.
2. Regional photo scanning services mostly serving/operating in a primary geographical area where clients can work directly with the provider.
3. Photo organizing/scanning services that come to your location and work on-site.
4. And, finally the D.I.Y. project folks.

There is new listing: http://photoscanningforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2 , currently being created that has identified over 800 photo scanning services throughout the U.S. from the first 3 groups that hopes to offer a way for individuals to research the best answer for them, including finding solutions to rent professional equipment for those who are looking for a DIY photo scanning project.